# Foreach end loop alert

Tags: php, html

So I have a foreach loop to insert values in my database and I want to display a alert when the loop ends and checks if the insertion was successfull

I have this

```php
if (isset($_POST['alter'])) {
  # code...
    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $id) {
      $array1 = $_POST['name'][$key];
      $array2 = $_POST['surname'][$key];
      $array3 = $_POST['tel'][$key];
      $array4 = $_POST['email'][$key];
      $query = $link -> prepare("UPDATE table SET name = ? , surname = ? , tel = ? , email = ? WHERE id = ?;");
      $query -> bind_param('sssss',$array1,$array2,$array3,$array4,$id);
      $s = $query -> execute();
      $query -> close();
      if ($s==1){
         ?><div class="alert alert-success">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
               <strong>SUCCESS!</strong>
           </div><?php
       } else {
           ?><div class="alert alert-danger">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- hidden="true">×</button>
                <strong>ERROR.</strong>
             </div><?php
       }
    }
}
```

but this will display multiple times the alert in the page

how can I make it display only one alert ?

Comment: Create an array with the successes, and you can store the variables you're updating. Then once the loop is done, create the alert.

Comment: Change the value of `$s` to something other than `1` inside the condition that creates the alert.

Comment: Do you want it to apply some of the changes, all up to a failure or rollback any changes if there is a failure?

Comment: @NigelRen I want to know what failed and the changes that didn't failed keep applying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To alert each update that failed, you can store the values in an array as you go through the loop. Then at the end of the loop, if that array is empty, you can give a success message, otherwise you echo a failure message and the contents of the failures array.

```
if (isset($_POST['alter'])) {
  # code...
    $failures = array();
    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $id) {
      $array1 = $_POST['name'][$key];
      $array2 = $_POST['surname'][$key];
      $array3 = $_POST['tel'][$key];
      $array4 = $_POST['email'][$key];
      $query = $link -> prepare("UPDATE table SET name = ? , surname = ? , tel = ? , email = ? WHERE id = ?;");
      $query -> bind_param('sssss',$array1,$array2,$array3,$array4,$id);
      if (!$query -> execute()) {
          $failures[] = "failed to update id $id with values ($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4)<br>";
      }
      $query -> close();
    }
    if (!count($failures)){
       ?><div class="alert alert-success">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
             <strong>SUCCESS!</strong>
         </div><?php
     } else {
         ?><div class="alert alert-danger">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- hidden="true">×</button>
              <strong>ERROR.</strong>
           <?php
           foreach ($failures as $failure) {
               echo $failure;
           }
           ?>   
           </div><?php
     }
}
```

Note that testing a boolean against `1`, while it will work in current PHP versions, is not good practice. You should use the boolean itself as the expression i.e. use `if ($success)`, not `if ($success == 1)`.

Comment: Okay I got it, but now it is not updating the values and it's displaying the success alert. hm

Comment: @JoãoNeves sorry about the lack of response, it's been night here. It seems I've missed a conversation here in the comments, but based on this and what was said in the comments to the question, I've updated my answer so that if there are any failures it will print a list of them. Take a look at this and if you have any issues please comment back so I can help you resolve them.

Comment: that worked like I wanted , I understood what you did here ! thanks for you help.